# How to store global Array of multiple items from a list for later use

Tags: java, html, selenium, arraylist

I have my selenium code which pulls a list of names available in the list. 
Now I want to store the same names as global for later use. Please help.

I have tried array process, it pulls only true with each line, but not the values.

```
List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"));

int total = allText.size();
System.out.println(total);

for(int i=3;i<=total;i++)
{
     CaselevelSigningCMs =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"+"["+i+"]"+"/td[2]")).getText();
     System.out.println(CaselevelSigningCMs);

}
```

I should get the names like: Ranjit Nyk, Sudhanva G.... I have to verify those names in other pages in other class/method. CaselevelSigningCMs is a global variable, it pulls single item only. I need similar array defined as global so that it can pull multiple items.

`CaselevelSigningCMs =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"+"["+i+"]"+"/td[2]")).getText();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how this String CaselevelSigningCMs  is defined. Just like that go for ArrayList

Lets say the string used is defined some where like

```
 public String CaselevelSigningCMs = "";
```

Similarly define ArrayList

```
 public List<String> collectedItems=new ArrayList<>();
```

in loop add  get text of each element, something like

```
 collectedItems.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"+"["+i+"]"+"/td[2]")).getText());
```

Comment: I have a situation using this. I have defined arraylist globally which pulls data from one method. when accessed the same in different method it shows blank

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Arraylist to store and retrieve them
```

ArrayList ts=new ArrayList();

store the objects in arraylist

ts.add();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stream.map() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) in order to convert the list of [WebElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) to the List of [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) containing element text attribute in a single shot:

```
List<String> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"))
        .stream()
        .map(WebElement::getText)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
allText.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I also don't really like your XPath expression, especially:

- `//*` wildcard
- these `table[2]` and `tr[3]`

wildcard expressions take longer time to execute and consume more resources, and your approach seems to be very dependent on [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_htmldom.asp) structure so I would recommend using [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) as well as [XPath Functions / Operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to make your expression as relative, robust and reliable as possible.

You can also consider using [Table](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) class of the [HtmlElements](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) framework for working with HTML [tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: I understand tht, its just for showing the sample xpath. I understand it takes time using wildcard expressions.